# Multimensional Array jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web

I'm have this form:

```
        <div data-role="content"> 
    <form action="#" method="post" id="cen">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contacto</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th >Mensaje</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                        
                    <td><input name="user" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="contacto@correo.com" style="width: 10em;"></td>
                    <td><input name="date" id="fecha" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'></td>
                    <td><input id="hora" name="hour" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 12}'></td>
                    <td><textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Su mensaje Aqui" style="width: 15em; max-width: 15em;"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Enviar" data-inline="true"></center>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My question is, how I can make that my form create field in real time? 
Beacause I need to provide users, with the ability to send as many informantion as the user want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the existing form elements like so:

```
var $clone = $("#cen").find("tbody").children().eq(0).clone(true);

$("#cen").find("tbody").append($clone);
```

This could easily be put in a `click` event handler:

```
$("#some-button").on("click", function () {

    var $clone = $("#cen").find("tbody").children().eq(0).clone(true);

    $("#cen").find("tbody").append($clone);

    return false;
});
```

I think the only other change you'd need to make ss changing the `name` attributes of your input elements by adding brackets to make them arrays `[]`. For example:

```
<input name="user[]" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="contacto@correo.com" style="width: 10em;">
```

That way no matter how many of these inputs exist, the data will make its way to the next page on submission of the form.

The server-side code that interprets this input should then attempt to loop through all the values by detecting how many exist, since the POST variables will be arrays, this shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I have one more question, after do that, How I can make references to the new elements? I mean, i will pass that by jquery to a web service, So how I reference the array?

Comment: @JosueFranciscoOrellanaVega Like I stated in my answer, your server-side script will access the same POST variables, but now instead of being strings, they will be arrays. So you can loop through the arrays and do whatever you need to with the data.

Comment: I alredy try what you sad, but I don't know why is not working

Comment: @JosueFranciscoOrellanaVega First, you should post what server-side language you're working with. Second, you should do a variable dump on the POST variable, in PHP this would be `var_dump($_POST);`. This will allow you to see exactly what data structure you're dealing with, and how to traverse it.

Comment: No, I mean that i use the code to create new elements and doesn´t work

Comment: i had this error 0x80020003 - JavaScript runtime error: Member not found.

Comment: @JosueFranciscoOrellanaVega I had omitted the `.clone(true)` call, notice the updated code in my answer. Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XjDpp/

Comment: Why have you used `return false;` at the end? Could you please explain? I'm curious to know. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Omar In a jQuery event handler, `return`ing `false` will both stop propagation of the event as well as prevent the default action from occurring for the event. It's similar to `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();` but it's a bit cleaner (although less verbose) to use `return false`. I tend to use it by default but I'd warn against doing that until you've got a good understanding of how that will affect your code. I find it helps me isolate code.